# How to obtain AsCII Code of a lowercase of an Uppercase in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I obtain AsCII Code of a lowercase of an Uppercase alphabet in Javascript

I understand I can  use `toLowerCase` or `toUpperCase` to do this but I don't wish to use them in this scenario:

So assuming I have this:

```
var string = "ABC".charCodeAt(0) //which returns 65 for character 'A'
```

How do do I get the lower case of 'A' without using `toLowerCase`

**Reason:** I am trying to build a custommized `toLowerCase` and `toUpperCase` based on what we are working on

Please pardon me if this is not possible. I just need a solution

Comment: Why do you not want to use `toLowerCase`?

Comment: I guess you'd have to map uppercase letters to lowercase letters and create a method that returns its lowercase equivalent.. But what is the reason to not use toLowerCase?

Comment: I am trying to build a custommized `toLowerCase` and `toUpperCase`

Comment: Those don't need to be customized. They handle whatever you throw at them correctly. If you have special cases, you should handle those separately, and then go for `toLowerCase()` for all other cases.

Comment: its a special case @AndersTornblad we are just experimenting on something new

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are definitely targetting **ASCII characters only** *(which seems to be really unuseful on the web in the year 2016, IMO)*, you can simply add 32 to it.

The distance between upper case characters and lower case characters in standard ASCII is 32.

```
A : 65    a : (65 + 32) = 97
B : 66    b : (66 + 32) = 98
C : 67    c : (67 + 32) = 99
...
```

**Code**

```
function asciiOnlyToLowerCase(input) {
    var result = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
        var charCode = input.charCodeAt(i);
        if (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) {
            // NOT an uppercase ASCII character
            // Append the original character
            result += input.substr(i, 1);
        } else {
            // Character in the ['A'..'Z'] range
            // Append the lowercase character
            result += String.fromCharCode(charCode + 32);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is a working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/atornblad/ym6znv6z/

Here is the article on ASCII on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters

**Opinion:**

*This being said, you should **really** go for using `toLowerCase()` or `toLocaleLowerCase()`, depending on your needs. That takes care of encoding issues beyond what was common in the 1980s and 1990s. Using standard functions, you get help with real-world scenarios, like non-english characters, non-latin characters, multi-byte characters, and so on...*

*The code I have written is probably the **wrong solution** for whatever you are doing.*